# Adding rows programatically to a DataGridView that is data bound?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem and I can't seem to be able to solve it. I thought someone here will be able to help out.

I have a form that has a DataGridView of customers. Now, I want to add several customers to this DataGridView without actually adding them to the database. This is because the client must be able to create a list of clients and when thats done add them all at once.

I have tried this:

```
string[] array = {"Microsoft", "Redmond", "Something"}
dataGridView.Rows.Add (array);
```

Now this can't be done because I get an exception saying something in the lines of *you cant add rows programatically to a DataGridView that is data bound*.

Now I have also read that this can be solved by using a table adapter to insert the rows instead of directly adding them via. a DGV. But this is also not possible because I use custom headers in the DGV because existing data is fetched via JOIN's so if I add them via a TableAdapter I get an exception that the it doesn't match the databases table schema.

Now I am really lost... Anyone know of a (halfway) elegant solution to this problem?

Thank you

Comment: What type is the DataSource that the DGV is bound to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your DGV to a `BindingList<YourObject>`, where `YourObject` can be a simple class with properties reflecting your database schema.  Initially populate the `BindingList` from the database, and the DGV will automatically add `YourObject` instances to the list.  When you're ready to commit the changes, do so manually from the BindingList.

Answer (score 1):

In order to show those rows, just do a UNION (-like) action before the databinding. Ie get your list of records, add the special ones and then databind.

Updating will require some special action(s) too. But with a total lack of details about your datastructures it's impossible to say what.

Comment: I am going to try to explain this as best as I can. I have a Link that is of the following structure: {LinkID, CustomerID, Type}. Now, the DataGridView I have should display the Name of the Customer, not ID (thats why I have JOIN's). Now I have a DGV with the headers | ID | NameOfCompany | but the underlying table structure is different. Customers are chosen from another form. So basically what I want: the DGV is data-bound. Add values programatically, when user is done adding Link's (and editing them), add them all to database...

Comment: Better to add such info to the question. You can add special records to a DataTable after the Adapter.Fill, and remove them before the Update. But altogether a `BindingList<MyClass>` might be just as easy.