# Rows cannot be programmatically added to the datagridview's row when control is data-bound

Tags: c#, datagridview

i need to insert rows in data grid so i use this code

dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

but i got this error rows cannot be programmatically added to the datagridview when the control is data bound . plz help to be able to add rows programmatically with the correct code

Comment: You must add rows to data source.

Comment: better have the data in a dataTable and put **dataGridView1.datasource= yourdataTable**;

Comment: hi Deepanshu ,could you show me an example as i still a beginner .

Answer (score 1):

[Answer By TreDubZedd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328769/adding-rows-programatically-to-a-datagridview-that-is-data-bound?rq=1)

Bind your DatagridView to a `BindingList<YourObject>`, where `YourObject` can be a simple class with properties reflecting your database schema. Initially populate the `BindingList` from the database, and the DGV will automatically add `YourObject` instances to the list. When you're ready to commit the changes, do so manually from the `BindingList`.